# Removing non-matching items from datasets

Tags: python, list, dataset, matching, nested-lists

I have two datasets consisting of lists of nested lists such that each item in the list looks like `list1[i]= [a, x, y b]` and `list2[j] = [c, x, y, d]` and where the length of the two lists does not necessarily match. I'd like to be able to go through the lists, preserve their order, and eliminate any of the sub-lists that do not contain matching `x` values. In the end, I want to get two lists of identical length and where for each index, the `x` value is the same in corresponding sub lists.

Right now I have a somewhat messy code that assumes that the set of `x` values in `list2` is a subset of those in `list1` (true at the moment) and then proceeds to remove items where the `x` values don't match.

```
    len_diff = len(list1) - len(list2)
    if len_diff > 0:
        removed = []
        for (counter, row) in enumerate(list2):
            while list1[counter][1] != list2[counter][1]:
                removed.append(list1.pop(counter))
        new_len_diff = len(list1) - len(list2)
        if new_len_diff < 0:
            raise IndexError('Data sets do not completely overlap')
        else:
            for i in range(new_len_diff):
                removed.append(temp_data.pop())
```

So basically I'm removing any items that don't `x` values match until they start matching again and then removing the end of `list1` beyond the `x` values in `list2` (raising an exception if I've cut too much out of `list1`).

Is there a better way to do this?

I don't necessarily need to relax the assumption that all `x` values in `list2` are in `list1` at the moment but it would make this code more useful to me in the future for other data manipulations. The biggest hole in my code now is that if there is a gap in my list1 data, I'll remove my entire list.

Comment: This looks like a situation where you might want to look at converting the lists to sets and using set_diff = set_one.difference(set_two).

Comment: @Tylerflick not if the OP wants order preserved

Comment: What would your desired results look like for your the list you posed above, @user47487?

Comment: @cdhagmann The desired result would be `list1` being the same length as `list2` and `list1[i][1] = list2[i][1]` for all `i`.

In the end, I want to compare the value `b` from `list1` to a function of the value `d` in `list2` for all points where they both exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
list1 = list2 = [x for x in list1 if x[1] in zip(*list2)[1]]
```

**EDIT**

Based on the comments below, the OP adapted this answer to do what was wanted by doing

```
list1 = [x for x in list1 if x[1] in zip(*list2)[1]]
list2 = [x for x in list2 if x[1] in zip(*list1)[1]]
```

Comment: This does not work with the structure of the lists I'm working with. `master_list = [x for x in list1 if x in list2]` returns `[]` because each item in list1 and list2 is a sublist itself and I only want to match a specific value in each sublist. In my example above `a!=b` and `c!=d`

Comment: Something similar works. You can't set the two lists equal (since that's not what I want). This achieves what I want:
`list1 = [x for x in list1 if x[1] in zip(*list2)[1]]; list2 = [x for x in list2 if x[1] in zip(*list1)[1]]`

Comment: @user47487, I am glad you found a solution that worked!

Comment: This not only accomplishes what my above code was doing but it also works for if `list2` has more points than `list1` and if there is a gap in the data. Thank you!